# Is Sulphurated Lime same as Lime Sulphur?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Pet dip lime sulphur has sulphurated lime

Lime sulphur for garden has lime sulphur

Will mixing sulphurated lime with HCl produce Hydrogen sulphite.

Answer (score 1):

No!
Both lime sulphur and sulfurated lime contain polysulfides - sulfur at a mix of -2 and 0 oxidation level. To get the sulfur to the +4 oxidation state as in sulfite you need an oxidising agent. HCl is not an oxidising agent

Comment: But mixing lime sulfur and HCl will produce hydrogen sulfide?

Comment: Correct, it will.

Comment: Will HCl 34% solution work or does it have to be 100%

Comment: 34% HCl is as strong a solution as you can get and will work

Comment: Ok. Is 'soluble sulfur' same as 'calcium polysulfides'. Will soluble sulfur mixed with HCl produce hydrogen sulfide

Comment: Not sure I can answer that. "Soluble sulfur" has no defined meaning. Somewhere on the product description there should be a table of contents with a more formal notification of what form of sulfur it contains.

Comment: Soluble sulphur present as polysulphide sulphur. Will this form Hydrogen Sulphide when mixed with HCl.